# Update Parent based on changes in 3 different child object records

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a parent "Contact" object which has 3 different child objects (Paid__c, Received__c, Forum__c) .

Based on changes in these 3 different objects, I would like to have a multi select picklist value on Contact to be updated.

Should I have three different triggers on each of the custom object to accomplish this? Is there any better way that everything can be handled in one place?

Answer (score 0):

If the child objects all have master-detail relationships with the parent, you can create rollup summary fields for each on the parent, and then a single parent trigger can do any additional logic that you'd like. See [Triggers and Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm) to see the various steps involved with saving for an idea of how a transaction executes in Salesforce.

Comment: I have the lookup relation for all three objects.

Comment: You can use the [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries tool](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) when you have lookup relationships instead of master-detail.